# use actionerror to display different errors on different atrtributes in the same form

Tags: jsp, struts2

this is my jsp code...

```
<div>
                <label for="customerCode"><span class="required">*</span>CustomerCode</label>
                <s:textfield name="customerCode"></s:textfield> 
                <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
                    <s:actionerror/>
                </s:if>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="customerName"><span class="required">*</span>Customer Name</label> 
                <s:textfield name="customerName"></s:textfield>
                <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
                    <s:actionerror />
                </s:if>
            </div>
```

Now, for the above code I have written a java file code snippet as below...

```
if(customerCode.isEmpty())
    {
        addActionError("Customer Code cannot be empty");
    }
    else if(alphaNumericCheck(customerCode)==1)
    {
        addActionError("Customer Code should be alphanumeric only");
    }
```

and validation for customerName as follows....

```
if(customerName.isEmpty())
    {
        addActionError("Customer Name cannot be empty");
    }
```

Now, the problem is that on validation the same messages get displayed on both the fields...
I have tried using addFieldError() . But, due to the css restriction it doesn't work.. 
Any Solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's *exactly* the fieldError use case. 
Use

```
addFieldError("customerCode", "Customer Code should be alphanumeric only" );
```

And

```
<s:fieldError fieldName="customerCode" />
```

And give your elements an ID equal to the name

Comment: The css used restricts this

Comment: Then validation gets done by using addFieldError but the message is not getting displayed...

Comment: Is there on html source? If it's just hidden, then override the css and display it. That's the way, you just need to make it works, not to find other ways

Comment: Ys I had to override the css to do it.